# An upper bound on the logarithm of factorial

Tags: inequality, logarithms, factorial

Does the following inequality hold:

$$ \ln(x!) \leq x \cdot \ln^{c}(x) $$

where $0<c<1$ is a real number?

I tried to use stirling approximation but failed.

Comment: If you know Stirling's approximation, you also know that $\log x!\sim x\log x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inequality is not true. Indeed, it is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^n \ln k\leq \ln^c n.
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^n\ln k\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n/2}^n\ln k\geq\frac{n}{4}\frac{1}{n}\ln (n/2).
$$
If the original inequality was true, we could deduce
$$
\frac{\ln (n/2)}{4}\leq \ln^c n,
$$
which is impossible for $0<c<1$.